# how to bigquery transfers: dataset projection

Tags: google-bigquery

Google seems to open up a new (beta) feature on **BigQuery's Data Transfers: Data Projection**.

It appears like we can copy all tables with data sampling, to another dataset.

Sadly there is a lack of documentation on how to transfer a sampling of tables from one dataset to another. In the definition of source, filters are asked, but no idea how to fill in (see the screenshot below). The question mark tip next to the "filter input" doesn't help, since it says: "Use filters to get a slice of dataset when project dataset in BigQuery."

What's confusing is, there are a number of tables in the source dataset, so it doesn't seem like writing filters specific to a table as in SQL. Rather I'm expecting sth like: ok take 20% of the rows depending on the data distribution on possible fields of ... (hopefully)

Does anyone know how to write the filters here?

[image: Data Source Definition and Filters]

Comment: If you click the link `This is the Dataset Projection configuration. Learn more ` at the top of the config you'll see the documentation which explains this in detail. I am not certain I can share it directly as for me it still shows as in Alpha.

Comment: How didn't I see that? Thank you. Let me check. I will update here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for "Ben P"'s guidance. I think it's still not possible to get a representative sampling from the data. It's rather a SELECT query with some extended regex for columns.

I think because of the beta it's not suitable to share the document here. But the document shows how to get some of the columns and rows according to usual SELECT/WHERE filters with predicate value.